# How to write a matrix as a product of elementary matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

\begin{pmatrix}3&-1&3\\ -2&3&2\\ 1&-3&1\end{pmatrix}

Any help would be greatly appreciated! 
I have done this before with other matrices, yet this one is bringing me trouble. I have spent too long on this as I believe it should be easy and yet my answers are always wrong.

What I am doing:
So I first row reduce it to the identity matrix:
I first switch R1 and R3
Then R3-3R1
then R2-2R1
then -1/3R2
then R3-8R1
then R2-2R1
then 3/32R3
then R1+3R3
and finally R2+4/3R3

I know there is many possible ways to get this too the identity matrix but this worked for me.
I then apply all of the above steps to identity matrices and multiply them together to check my work but it never works out to be the original matrix so I am forced to believe something is wrong

Comment: Please do not repost the same question!

Comment: Edit your previous post to include your working. We know you made a mistake. Show us your working and we can spot the mistake.

Comment: Ok I will add my work now, sorry I am new tot this site.

Comment: The determinant is $32$, it is indeed nonsingular.

Comment: Yes, and therefore it can be written as a product of elementary matrices. I just can't seem to do it.

Comment: I copied and pasted the content of this post to your previous question. Feel free to [delete](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that/5222#5222) this one.

Comment: Thank you! Really appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

1. Apply Gauss-Jordan elimination reducing to identity
2. Express each step in Gauss-Jordan elimination a multiplication by an elementary matrix.
3. Invert the matrices and multiply in reverse order.

Answer (score 0):

Guide:

Reduce the matrix to Reduced Row echelon form using elementary operations.

$$E_k \ldots E_1 A = I$$

Solve for $A$.